# How to assign Permissions to site page dynamically when created

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In Liferay when a site page is added, it is assigned `VIEW` permission automatically for `Owner` role, `Guest` role and `Site Member` role.

Is it possible to assign `VIEW` permissions dynamically to custom role when page is created instead of manually assigning `VIEW` permission from Manage-permission tab of the site-page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the possible way is Using `LayoutListener` via hook

For this you need to create hook (portal properties) and override following property:

```java
value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.Layout
```

See the following example:

```java
value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.Layout=com.smb.mypermissions.hook.listeners.LayoutListener
```

Here `LayoutListener` is the custom class created under package `com.smb.mypermissions.hook.listeners` to override default `LayoutListener`.

Signature for this class: `public class LayoutListener extends BaseModelListener<Layout>`

Now override the method

```java
public void onAfterCreate(Layout model)throws ModelListenerException
```

to assign permission to the role, use following one liner:

```java
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(
    companyId, Layout.class.getName(),
    ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,
    String.valueOf(primKey), role.getRoleId(),
    new String[] {
        ActionKeys.VIEW
    });
```

where role can be obtained from `RoleLocalServiceUtil` and `primkey` is the page unique id i.e `plid`

```java
long primKey = model.getPlid();

long companyId = model.getGroup().getCompanyId();

Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(companyId, "<Your Role name here>");
```